# How to stop reducing life?

Tags: java, slick

***CODE***

```
Input input = gc.getInput();
            int xpos = Mouse.getX();
            int ypos = Mouse.getY();
            emu = "Enemy Life : " + enemyLife; 
            Life = "Your Life Is" + life;
            Mousepos = "X:" + xpos + "Y:" + ypos;
            //test
            test1 = "Test INT" + test1int;
            if(!repeatStop)
            {
                       //if this button is press, the damage will add up. When 
                        //pressed fight, it would start reducing the enemy health.

            if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_1))
            {
                test1int += 1;
            }

            }
            if((xpos>1007 &xpos<1297)&&(ypos>881 && ypos<971))
            {
                            //Fight button
                if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
                    finishTurn=true;
                }
            }
                  //fight has started
            if(finishTurn==true)
            {
                         //this would reduce the enemy life
                if(floodControl1==false)
                {
                enemyLife-=test1int;
                }
                           //PROBLEM: Does not stop reducing! 

                           //the below code was not successful. It did not stop it //         from reducing further.
                if(test1int>10)
                {
                    floodControl1=true;
                }
            }
```

***QUESTION:***
Ok now, this is what is does. When I press the key, 1, it adds up the damage to the enemy. When I press fight, It will then start to reduce the enemy's health. Now my problem is, it kept on reducing and deducting it until negative! How do I deduct it to my desired damage (My desired damage is the one when press key 1)?

Comment: -1 This is not a question about game development, but about a basic programming problem.

Comment: SystemNetworks. You really, really need to read the FAQ about what kinds of questions to ask here. I've told you this a few times, and you're still posting these localized-asking-for-code questions. That's not what this site is about. Please read and understand the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 3):

Just make a global field that records the damage to be dealt (the value obtained when pressing one), then when you press left, before decrementing the life, deduct the amount to decrement it with from the damage to be dealt value and check if that damage to be dealt value is still positive. When it becomes negative that means you've dealt enough damage and you should stop.

Comment: can you give me a code at least? I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Your will stop decrementing *enemyLife* when the *floodControl1* is set to *true* right?

And you do:

```
if(test1int>10)
{
    floodControl1=true;
}
```

*test1int* is incremented when you press the key *1*. I can't see how you initialize the *test1int* variable in your code but assuming the following:

- test1int = 0
- I press the key *1* less than 10 times (so the value of *test1int* will be lower than 10)
- I press the left click of the mouse

You will never stop decreasing your *enemyLife* variable since test1int < 10.

Here is a more *natural* way to do what you want:

```
if (floodControl1==false) {
    if (enemyLife - test1int < 0) { //check if reducing the enemyLife will not make it negative
        //stop decreasing
        enemyLife = 0;
        floodControl1 = true;
    } else {
        //continue decreasing
        enemyLife -= test1int;
    }
}
```